# jQuery Cycle Plugin slideshow with Vimeo videos

Tags: jquery, video, slideshow, cycle, vimeo

I am trying to incorporate Vimeo videos into my jQuery Cycle slideshow.

The videos work great in the slideshow, however with the new `<iframe>` embed system, I can't seem to get the videos to stop the slideshow when the viewer presses play on the video.

I need to use the new `<iframe>` system for use on mobile devices.

This is the jQuery for the slideshow:

```
jQuery('#imagegallery').cycle({
    fx: 'scrollHorz'
});
```

This is the embed code:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/23565246?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="584" height="328" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Slideshow structure:

```
<div id="imagegallery>
<span><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/23565246?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="584" height="328" frameborder="0"></iframe></span>
<span style="display:none;"><iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/23565246?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="584" height="328" frameborder="0"></iframe></span>
</div>
```

Any ideas on this would be greatly appreciated! I am decent at jQuery, I just think something is happening with the `<iframe>` embed system.

Thanks, 
Dan

Answer (score 2):

A couple of ideas..

Try using the  **pause** option of the cycle plugin and make sure you check this page [http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/options.html] for more options.

Another idea, since the videos are contained in iframes check for events 'raised' by the iframe (hover maybe)? and stop the cycle plugin (see the stop option in the options page).

In general try to identify which events can be raised and if/when they are instruct the plugin to 'stop' the animation.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem a while ago, too, so I thought I'd post my answer ... it worked with the pause option. I couldn't find a way to capture the "play" event through the iframe, so I just paused the video when the user mouses over the iframe. By using play and pause controls, at least the user was able to see when the slideshow was playing or paused.

I just appended a `.video` class to all the iframe elements

```
$('.video').mouseover(function() {
        $('.slideshow').cycle('pause');
    });
```

Again, in my case, if the video finished, or the user wanted to move on, I used a "play" button to keep the slideshow going.